# Change visual studio debugging shortcut keys

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to change the visual studio debugging shortcut keys, no matter what key I assign they seem to be reverting back to the old Function keys.  Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: Which VS version did you use? What shortcut keys did you set for the VS debugging? Can you share us more detailed information/steps about it?

Comment: any update? What about this issue?

Answer (score 4):

For example, I remove the F11 for Step into, and then assign it to "Start debugging". It also works well in my side after I restart the VS.

(1) Please disable all extension tools like Resharper or others.

(2) Like the screen shot 2, please make sure that the same shortcut key was not used by other options under "Shortcut currently used by".

(3) Please reset your VS settings, and then run your VS as the admin, re-assign the shortcut key, check it again.

[image]

[image]